# What were the two bottles that Sebastian found before he got stabbed?

Tags: black-butler

At the end of chapter 48 in the *Black Butler* manga, right after Siemens was brought to the cellar, Sebastian examines the hearth of the room where Siemens stayed.

He finds **two vials** right before he was “killed” by Earl Grey.

> [image: the two vials]

However, in chapter 47, when they framed Woodley for Siemens’ murder, Sebastian only pieces together **one vial**.

> [image: only one vial]

Why? And what was the other vial for?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not following the series, but after a quick read from chapter 47-50, there doesn't seem to be any explicit mention about the 2nd vial...